# В/тайне: слитно или раздельно в данном контексте?

Tags: предлоги, слитно-раздельно

Нужно ли писать слово *втайне* слитно в следующем контексте:

> Теперь каждый втайне мечтал после смерти откочевать в счастливые кущи.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае писать нужно слитно - **втайне**, поскольку в данном контексте **втайне** – наречие, образованное от существительного **тайна** с предлогом. Оно синонимично наречию **тайком**.

*Теперь каждый **втайне** мечтал после смерти откочевать в счастливые кущи.*

https://kak-pravilno.net/vtayne-ili-v-tayne-kak-pravilno/